# Runing SparkPi in Kubernetes throws AccessDeniedException when Docker image uses non-root user

Tags: apache-spark

Using Spark 2.4.4

I have a docker image that starts up as a non-root user. The spark software is in a directory owned by the user, and I am able to run the SparkPi example (as the non-root user) from within the image using this command:

```
/opt/nsp/spark/bin/spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --name spark-pi \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
  --conf spark.driver.memory=1G \
  --conf spark.executor.memory=1G \
  --conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
  local:///opt/nsp/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
```

This completes successfully.

When I try to run it on a Kubernetes cluster using spark-submit, I get java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException.

I see this in the executor log:

```
20/01/27 14:48:46 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://spark-pi-1580136512257-driver-svc.nsp.svc:7078/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar to /var/data/spark-ebbc540f-5256-4ef4-8568-9b22233bcc42/spark-a3dadf1e-e21f-4df6-a985-75ff161e6c80/fetchFileTemp1549348282821390884.tmp
20/01/27 14:48:46 INFO Utils: Copying /var/data/spark-ebbc540f-5256-4ef4-8568-9b22233bcc42/spark-a3dadf1e-e21f-4df6-a985-75ff161e6c80/2218273401580136519157_cache to /./spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
20/01/27 14:48:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: ./spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
```

It looks like the executor fetches the jar file and puts it into the scratch directory. But then it tries to copy it to the root '/' directory, to which the non-root user does not have access.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to get this to work?

Thanks

---

Edit:

I believe I figured out what is happening.

I am creating a non-root user called 'nsp' in the Dockerfile and setting the image to use that user. However, it looks like the working directory when I run the docker image is not the home directory of the 'nsp' user, it is the root directory.

```
[vagrant@nsp-v6 ~]$ docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh 2ab0208bd5f5
sh-4.4$ id
uid=1000(nsp) gid=1000(nsp)
sh-4.4$ pwd
/
sh-4.4$
```

If this same situation occurs when spark-submit creates the pod from the docker image, then the executor is trying to create a file in its working directory of '/', but does not have permission since it is not the root user.

Indeed, I modified the entrypoint.sh script to change the directory before running the executor command:

```
# Execute the container CMD under tini for better hygiene
cd ~
exec /sbin/tini -s -- "${CMD[@]}"
```

The execution is now successful.

---

Edit #2

It looks like I can accomplish the same thing by using the WORKDIR directive in the Dockerfile.